# Unset ?_SESSION before assign ?_SESSION php

Tags: php, session

I have an Index page with a table and some rows. Each row has onclick event with link to my second page, the onclick event assign an ID from that table and put it into the $_SESSION(). Now when I return to my index, it is intended that the user clicks again on a table row, this would start the session process from beginning.

But to have an unset session on that index.php site, can I unset the $_SESSION once the user is on that index.php site? Similar to the below, unset, wait for the click and set the session according to the value.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION))
    {
        session_unset();
        session_start();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by giving unset $_SESSION is like deleting the whole global SESSION array but here you should use  unset $_SESSION['id'] coz  you are assigning id only

Example (for clarificaton)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['previous_page']) && isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
   unset $_SESSION['id'];
   header("Location:index.php"); // for returning to index page
 }
 ?>
  //and put session_start(); the moment your id is assigned
  // $_SESSION['id']= $_POST['id']
```

Comment: Valid point. I tested unset and it seems similar to clear cache. I will use unset with the id.

Comment: yup you were  simply using unset $_SESSION and that was deleting the whole array  check this out here              (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)

Answer (score 1):

you can use session_destroy();

hope this help you..